# How to paste raw HTML into an email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, html

I would like to send an HTML Newsletter from my Gmail account.

I have the raw HTML, but how can I paste it into the editor, so Gmail will recognize it as HTML?

Is this even possible?

Comment: even if not a direct response to the question, i suggest to take a look at http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ for some tips and tricks in the event of sending marketing emails.

Comment: some of these no longer work

Comment: http://flashissue.com seems to be aiming to solve exactly that. You can create your own with drag / drop or paste HTML

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question of how to use the browser client, but it does solve your problem:  use the Thunderbird email client to send html using a Gmal account.  It allows you to insert html as a native feature.

Comment: btw, you can inspect (right click > inspect) the "white space" in the mail box, and paste there the HTML (btw, it's not guarantee that you will see the same thing on the receiver mail client...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Gmail doesn't support it out of the box. The only possibility is using some software like Thunderbird and send the mail via SMTP to your mail-account.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a great way to set up html for copying straight into gmail. I just type the HTML into the html section click run, it then gets rendered in the result section, you can then select an copy it from there into email message. Bearin mind that for security reasons gmail strips alot of 'fancy'  html and strips all scripting.

Comment: Well, Thunderbird was the best solution. I selected edit source code and in one minute I Sent my email marketing perfectly.

Comment: A reference for Thunderbird HTML editing is http://kb.mozillazine.org/Edit_HTML_source.

Answer (score 84):

You can actually work around this if you're using a browser with a developer tool that allows you to edit the page's DOM (source), like Chrome, or Firefox with Firebug.

If you're using Chrome, you compose a new email in Gmail, type in some a dummy text, select it, and right click in the email body and select 'inspect element'. Highlight the dummy text, right click and select 'edit as HTML'. Paste in your HTML.

When you send your email it should send your edited HTML (provided you haven't done anything too crazy that Gmail prevents).

Answer (score 32):

If you copy and paste the source code, you will get the source code in your email, but if you copy and paste what you see in your browser, you will get a (mostly) acceptable rendition of your original HTML.

You just have to make sure that you are using the "[rich formatting](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8260)" mode.

The big downside is that you cannot ever (as far as I can see) edit the source code directly, and the built-in editor is rather limited.

Comment: Yes, good solution.  (I just use Komposer to edit simple HTML.)

Answer (score 11):

Open a text editor. Paste your HTML into it, and save the file with a .html extension. Open that file in your web browser (this will render the HTML). Select and copy the contents of that page (this will copy the content as text/html). Paste into your email.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick and user friendly way to paste your HTML into Gmail using a newsletter creator for Gmail called [FlashIssue](http://Flashissue.com) (full disclosure - I'm the founder).

We've had a HTML authoring tool for Gmail for a while - it lets you create a full styled newsletter and helps with finding and adding content to the newsletter rapidly. you then send out the newsletters through your gmail contacts.

[image]

Once you're in the app you can paste your HTML into one of our content boxes using "source" button.

The web app is free to use. let me know if you need anymore help.

You can install the extension (chrome) or login to the web app for free from our website (address above).

Comment: How do you actually use this? I have installed it, and all I got is a grayed icon in the extension bar, nothing changed in gmail.

Comment: doesnt show html code after copying it