# Send Google spreadsheet with embedded HTML in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, html

When I try to publish content from Google Spreadsheet, it puts it into an HTML iframe. This is found under `File > Publish to Web`.

How can I send this iframe content in a mail, sent over Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Writing HTML in the Gmail [is not possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3555/408) so you'll have to use another client to compose your email. But especially for `iframe` I don't think that anyone will be able to see it, since it has some security issues and most likely Gmail will block the contents of it. Consider sending it as an image.